# How to pass DateTime object as json in .net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I Have a model which has DateTime type in it:

```
    public class ToDo
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parentId { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public DateTime due { get; set; }
        public ToDo(int id, int parentId, string note, DateTime due)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.parentId = parentId;
            this.note = note;
            this.due = due;
        }
    }
```

I've created a controller for this class to send my post requests through api. but I don't know how to bind DateTime type to json i've tried a request with the following body but it didn't work out:

```
    {"parentId":1,"note":"hello world","due":{"year":2017,"month": 11,"day":25}}
```

How should I post the DateTime type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently one of the ways you can do it is this:

```
{"due": "2017-11-01T00:00:00"}
```

it was actually an easy question but if you want to make sure how to make a proper post request for unknown object types format it's best to send an object with empty body to see the default values.

Answer (score 3):

For `DateTime` Type property, you need to pass the String which could be converted to `DateTime` Type.

For `{"year":2017,"month": 11,"day":25}`, it is object instead of String, it will fail to convert to DateTime.

For anything which could be converted to `DateTime` by `Convert.ToDateTime` and `DateTime.Parse`.

So, both `{"parentId":1,"note":"hello world","due":"05/05/2005"}` and `{"parentId":1,"note":"hello world","due":"2018-05-10"}` will work, you could make test with the DateTime string you need.